# AspCore using Docker on Mac

Tags: macos, docker, asp.net-core

I was trying to implement aspcore project using docker on mac. I have done all the settings like creating docker file but, getting the message:
**Now listening on: http://localhost:5000**

However, not able to browse using the above link."Failed to open the page".
My docker file:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:latest

WORKDIR /app

COPY /app /app

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WildestDreams.dll"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure (or try) the following things:

- Your ASP.NET Core application is published and you are copying only published files to the image.
- You are exposing the port 5000 from the Container i.e. add `EXPOSE 5000` in the Dockerfile.
- You are mapping the container and host ports correctly.
- Try ASP.NET Core `aspnetcore:lts` instead of the SDK image as it will expose port 80 by default and is much smaller and faster than the SDK image.

Comment: Issue fixed. I tweaked my docker file [added expose] and also my ipaddress .I was not using the correct IP . Use this command to get the details of ports and ipaddress linked to your docker container. $(docker ps -q).